# Recursively Comparing Items in a List

Tags: python

I've generated a unique list of strings. Each string is 6 numbers separated by a colon. The list of strings has been sorted from largest to smallest by the first number then progressively by 2nd, 3rd, and so on. Example snippet below:

```
UniqueTierHash = [ '6:3:5:6.5:5:2.5',
                   '6:3:5:5.5:5:3.5',
                   '6:2.5:5:5:4:3',
                   '6:2.5:5.5:5.5:4.5:3.5',
                   '5.5:4.5:4.5:4.5:5.5:4.5' ]
```

I'm trying to take this list and compare one item to the next keeping cases where each of the 6 numbers is larger or equal to the next item. Initially, I wrote a function that did this, but it ended up returning all of the strings. This is because a lesser string would be subsequently compared to the next string, and being different, both would be retained.

```
TierHashKeep = []

for i in UniqueTierHash:

    if UniqueTierHash.index(i) == len(UniqueTierHash) - 1: break

    test = function.CompareTierHash(i,UniqueTierHash[UniqueTierHash.index(i) + 1])
    print(i + ' \n' + UniqueTierHash[UniqueTierHash.index(i) + 1])
    print(test)

    if test == False:
        TierHashKeep.append(i)
        TierHashKeep.append(UniqueTierHash[UniqueTierHash.index(i) + 1])
    elif test == True:
        TierHashKeep.append(i)
    else:
        print('Error in TierCompare')
```

I suspect that I need to employ some kind of recursive evaluation of the UniqueTierHash and remove items as I iterate through the list. Any suggestions on how best to approach this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to handle such data is to put it in a NumPy array. One way to do the filtering is to initialize a list with just the first row of the full array, and then iterate over the other rows of the full array, comparing each one to the last element of the new list, and adding it to the new list if all its elements are smaller:

```py
import numpy as np

list_of_strings = ['6:3:5:6.5:5:2.5', # data slightly changed for testing
                   '6:3:5:5.5:5:3.5',
                   '6:2.5:5:5:4:2',
                   '6:2.5:5.5:5.5:4.5:3.5',
                   '5.5:1:1:1:1:0.5']

numbers = np.array([s.split(':') for s in list_of_strings], 
                   dtype=float)

numbers_descending = [numbers[0]]

for row in numbers[1:]:
    if all(row <= numbers_descending[-1]):
        numbers_descending.append(row)

numbers_descending = np.array(numbers_descending)

numbers_descending
```

```
array([[6. , 3. , 5. , 6.5, 5. , 2.5],
       [6. , 2.5, 5. , 5. , 4. , 2. ],
       [5.5, 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 0.5]])
```

Comment: +1. The only thing I personally would recommend doing differently is replacing `for i in range(1, len(numbers)):` with something like `for number in numbers:`. Python's for loops are great at what they do, and it's usually [more readable](https://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/) to use them as intended than to force them to act like other languages' index-based for loops.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyChucky, that's a good point. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Took me a little bit to figure it out (new to Python), but I get it. Looking back to the "saved array" (numbers_descending) makes more sense than trying to look ahead in the same array. I kept my approach of splitting only the two strings vs. the whole string as I anticipate having several very large arrays and I'm trying to minimize the overhead. I really like the 'all()' method, way better than the little for loop in my function. The clincher was that 'numbers_descending[-1])' part. I had no idea you could do that. Very cool. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're making life hard for yourself here; if you want regular access to the index of an element, you should iterate the list with something like `for index, hash in enumerate(UniqueTierHash)`, but in this case I don't think you really need the index; you just want access to two adjacent elements, so you can grab the first element and then iterate over the remaining list, retaining the "previous" value each time. An alternative method would be to iterate just over indices and grab the elements directly each time through the loop.

I have only retained the actual values that pass your test here; you seemed to be keeping all values and some twice.

```py
UniqueTierHash = [ '6:3:5:6.5:5:2.5',
                   '6:3:5:5.5:5:3.5',
                   '6:2.5:5:5:4:3',
                   '6:2.5:5.5:5.5:4.5:3.5',
                   '5.5:4.5:4.5:4.5:5.5:4.5' ]

TierHashKeep = []

this_hash = UniqueTierHash[0] # first element to start the pairing

for next_hash in UniqueTierHash[1:]: # iterate through rest of list

    test = function.CompareTierHash(this_hash, next_hash)

    print(this_hash + ' \n' + next_hash) ####### check #
    print(test) ####### check #

    if test == True:
        TierHashKeep.append(this_hash)
    elif test != False:
        print('Error in TierCompare')

    this_hash = next_hash # roll forward to the next pair

print(TierHashKeep) ####### check #
```

Comment: I am new to Python so it is taking me a little while to understand the syntax and methods you are suggesting. Just to clarify, I am currently using '.split()' for the actual comparision. It lives in the CompareTierHash (which is working correctly). All the for loop is doing is passing the current item and the next item to the compare function which is just returning a boolean. Thanks.

Comment: Updated to explain and clarify, as well as retaining your test call.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was unintentionally keeping all the values and some twice due to how I was running my comparison with some unfortunate logic. I'm now looking back to the last keep array as I progress with the unique array for the comparisons. Now, it is functioning as intended. Thanks.